# Does Golang Copy the String on Modification/Write?

Tags: go

After reading the answer on [Does Go language use Copy-on-write for strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532127/does-go-language-use-copy-on-write-for-strings/)
, I feel the question was not adequately answered.

Given the example below, what is actually happening under the hood?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
  s := "Hello"
  t := s // t shares the same data as s
  s += "World" // a new string is created
  t += "There" // a new string is created.

  fmt.Printf("%s %s\n", s, t)
}
```

output:

```
HelloWorld HelloThere
```

The question is when will golang determine there is a need to create a new copy?

Comment: strings are immutable in Go, so there is no "modification" of string values in go. You can change the value stored in a variable but that's not the same.

Comment: @mkopriva, I understand that is is immutable other than append operation. Please refer to the code, both s and t are sharing the same underlying data at the beginning, but later on, t will become a separate copy, so is it true that Go copies the string when u attempt to modify the underlying data?

Comment: "no new string is being created" - source for this assertion?

Comment: @mkopriva, that is not true, when we assign s to t, they are in fact pointing to the same address which holds the string data.

Comment: @Mox yes? explain this then https://play.golang.com/p/-3d-x_LiT4U

Comment: @Mox: You are wrong and mkopriva is right.

Comment: @mkopriva, what u r printing are the address of the 2 variable, it does not mean they are not pointing to the same memory space. And it is precisely that they are immutable, u can have 2 strings pointing to the same address without any problem.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, oh thanks for pointing out that mistake.

Comment: @Mox you're right, my bad. The two variables do indeed point to the same data. However, it still stands, that any kind of attempt at "modification" of that data (e.g. `a += b`, etc.) creates a new string, at a new place in memory. https://play.golang.com/p/tiJX6BL-ogJ

Comment: @mkopriva, yes that is why by definition, it is called copy on write. there is a similar example on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write. The reason why i reposted this question because the answer to the old question failed to answer it.

Comment: actually, i m looking for an answer that points to the internal implementation when a given golang string is modified.

Comment: @Mox but how can you modify something that's immutable? Are you specifically looking for the implementation of `+=` when the operands are strings?

Comment: @mkopriva, a friend of mine shared this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#Copy-on-write

Comment: "internal implementation when a given golang string is modified" doesn't exist. Strings are immutable. Therefore, there is zero code dedicated to mutating them, by definition. When you `s += "foo"`, a *new string* is created which is the concatenation of the old value with `"foo"`, and that *new string* is stored into `s`, replacing the previous value.

Comment: @Adrian that means golang implements copy on write. pls read the wiki links i have shared.

Comment: You keep bringing up COW and I'm not entirely sure why. If you think you have a better answer than everyone else, you can answer your own question. If you have a question and want answers, that is exactly what the SO community is here for. If you have an opinion and want to engage in a debate, try a forum like Reddit or Google Groups.

Comment: I have read your link BTW, and it *does not describe what happens in Go*. The phrase "copy on write" could be construed to describe what I explained in my earlier comment, but "copy-on-write" as a CE concept as described on that WP page is *not* what is happening here.

Comment: The title of your question does not mention COW. Per wiki COW: "when a user asks the system to copy an object, it instead merely creates a new reference that still points to the same object. As soon as a user attempts to modify the object through a particular reference, the system makes a real copy, applies the modification to that, and sets the reference to refer to the new copy." *That is not what is happening in Go, **nothing** is being done automatically or behind the scenes.*

Comment: @Adrian that is the behaviour of the code in my question, t shares the same underlying byte data as s. And when it is being “modified”, a new copy is created. Golang does it automatically.

Comment: It doesn't do it automatically. Your code does it explicitly, as I said in my earlier comment. `s += "World"` creates a new string and assigns it to the variable `s`. Nothing automatic, nothing behind the scenes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Go, string values are `read-only` byte slices and you cannot change its elements (immutable). Since it is a slice, it means that it has a backing (underlaying) array that has defined capacity. This being said, we can say that string is a data structure that points to a read-only backing array.

Strings are optimized for high reusability and thus read-only. Whenever you modify a string a new string (byte slice) is created in the background which makes it a bit of costly operation. One recommendation is to convert a string to an actual byte slice `[]byte(string)` and work with bytes or use [strings.Builder](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Builder) when your program needs to do a lot of string manipulations.

```
s := "Hello" // backing array for "hello" created; `s` points to the backing array
t := s // `t` a new string structure and points to the same backing array as `s`, 
s += "World" // new backing array created for "HelloWorld"; `s` points to the new backing array
t += "There" // `t` was still pointing to "Hello" and with this operation, a new backing array is created for "HelloThere" and `t` points to it
```

[StringHeader - data structure](https://golang.org/src/reflect/value.go?s=56526:56578#L1873)

[String Data Type in GO](https://medium.com/rungo/string-data-type-in-go-8af2b639478)

Comment: therefore Golang implements Copy on write/modification on string, m i rite?

Comment: @Mox: no, this term means something else. You don't "write" to an existing string here. You explicitly create a new one.

Comment: Yes, copies the old value and creates new with the modifications made 

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, that is what we called copy on write. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write

Comment: @mox no. COW involves modifiable shared resources. You don’t have those here.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, May I point you to the book "Go Programming Language", Turn to section 3.5 on String. It is clearly explained there.

Comment: @Mox: Yes, let's it read it, shall we? The very first sentence of the chapter says “A string is an immutable sequence of bytes.” And because it's immutable, there are no writes. Hence "copy on __write__" is not applicable. If you want new strings, _you_ have to create them. Not some background COW magic.

Comment: @Mox: seeing that you accepted this answer (which says the same thing as me), I'm not sure what you're arguing about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197813/discussion-between-sergio-tulentsev-and-mox).

Answer (score 1):

After much debate/discussion on this at the comment sections, here is my conclusion.

Golang does not have copy-on-write.

The **+=** here is an explicitly creating a new string which is equivalent to **s = s + "World"** which creates a new string and assign it back to **s**

And if you try to write the following code, it will result in compilation error due to immutability of the Golang string

```
t[0] = 'A' // cannot assign to t[0]
```

As a result, everything in Golang is explicit, nothing is done implicitly by Golang. That is why copy-on-write does not exist in Golang.

Note: COW and immutability are not mutually exclusive.